# Performance Impact of turning Columns into Rows

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, javadb

I'm planning to use JavaDB (Derby) or PostgreSQL.

I have the following problem: I need to store a large set of vectors. Currently all vectors contain a fixed number of elements. Hence the appropriate way of storing the set is using one row per vector and a column per element. However, the number of elements might change over time. Additionally, in my case, from a software engineering perspective, having a fixed number of columns reflects knowledge about a software component which the general model should be unaware of.

Therefore I'm thinking about "linearizing" the layout and use a general table that stores elements instead of vectors.

The first element of the vector 5 could then be queried like this:

`SELECT value FROM elements where v_id = 5 and e_id = 1;`

In general, I do not need full table reads, and only a relatively small subset of the vectors is accessed.

Maybe database-savvy people can judge what the performance impact will be?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a variant of what's referred to in general database terms as [Entity-Attribute-Value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) or EAV design. It's a bit of a relational database design anti-pattern and should be avoided in most cases. Performance tends to be poor due to the need for many self-joins, and queries are ugly at best.

In PostgreSQL look into the `intarray` extension, it should solve your problem pretty ideally if the values are simple integers. Otherwise consider PostgreSQL's standard array types. They've got their own issues, but are generally a lot better than EAV, though they're not lovely to work with from JDBC.

Otherwise, if *all* you're storing is these vectors, maybe consider a non-relational DB.

Comment: Look into hstore, json and xml types, too.